# Outputting an sqlite record in Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I am currently producing a stock management system. All of the code so far works, however i have a variable which asks a user to input an ingredient name. If the ingredient name if found within the "inventory" table of the database i have created, then the record will be displayed to the user. Within each record, there are the fields: Ingredient, stock_level, Price, and Retailer. I'm not sure how to output the whole record to the user.

I have tried using the print(fetchone()), however if an ingredient is held in the database, "None" is outputted instead of the actual record

```
def searchIngredient():
    found=0
    while found == 0:
        ingredient = input("Enter an ingredient name: ")

        if len(ingredient) < 3:
            print("Ingredient name must be three or more characters long")
            continue

        with sqlite3.connect("Inventory.db") as db:
            cursor = db.cursor()
        findIngredient = ("SELECT * FROM Inventory WHERE Ingredient=?")
        cursor.execute(findIngredient, [(ingredient)])

        if cursor.fetchall():
            print(fetchone())
        else:
            found = 0
            print("Ingredient does not exist in Inventory")
            tryAgain = input("Do you want to enter another Retailer? Y or N ")
            if tryAgain.lower() == "n":
                mainMenu()
    time.sleep(2)
    mainMenu()
```

When run with the rest of the code, the user is asked to input an ingredient name (the format check works if string is less than three characters). With the fetchone() function, "None" is outputted when an ingredient name what exists in the db is entered. If the ingredient does not exist, the code works also. It is just the case of outputting the record to the user.

Answer (score 0):

You are not fetching the record, instead:

```
# returns a list
for rec in cursor.fetchall():
    # do something

# or
while True:
   rec = cursor.fetchone()
   if not rec:
        break
   # do something
```

Since fetch all the records can cause a very large list, it is recommended to loop over the records until you met `None` - no more to read. Look into [the doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) for more information.

---

Also Python has a standard lib [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html). You don't have to print.

Example:

```
logger = logging.getLogger("SQL query")
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

logger.info("QUERY: %s" % query)
```

You can save it to a file:

```
hdlr = logging.FileHandler('query.log')
logger.addHandler(hdlr)
```

See [the cookbook](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html) for more examples.